# Complex Monge-Ampere equation with degenerate right hand side

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

Given a Kahler manifold $(X, \omega_0)$, and a smooth function $f$, suppose that I have a smooth solution to the following complex Monge-Ampere equation:

$(\omega_0 +i \partial \bar \partial \varphi)^n = e^{f} \omega_0^n$

By the classical result of pluripotential theory, $\sup_{X}|\varphi|$ can be estimated by $\|e^f\|_{L_p( \frac{\omega_0^n}{n!})}$, for $p > 1$. Now suppose instead I only have control for $\|e^{f+g}\|_{L_p( \frac{\omega_0^n}{n!})}$, where $g$ is $-\infty$ on some measure zero set and smooth outside this set. I wonder whether there has been any results on bounding $sup_{X} |\varphi|$ in terms of $\|e^{f+g}\|_{L_p( \frac{\omega_0^n}{n!})}$.

By degenerate I mean that $e^{pg} \frac{\omega_0^n}{n!}$ is a positive measure but not a volume form. Not sure whether this is the right terminology.

Comment: The same paper that proves the classical result that you state also proves what you want: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485891130 Theorem 2.5.2 and Example 2 after that

Comment: I see, and thank you. Never really actually read the original paper.